# IF/ CASE + math operation - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 5 columns in table:

```
               - id / a /b /operation/ c
```

where for example:    1 / 2 /3 / +       / 5

What is my goal is to check if operation (+/-/*/%) is correct with the formula (a (operation) b = c) and show only those records where formula is true.

Honestly I've been trying to solve that but unfortunately I really don't know how to...

For sure I have to start with operation column:

```
  (IF(operation = '+', a+b, IF( operation = '-', a-b, IF(operation = '*', a*b, IF(operation = '/',a/b, ''))))
```

Shall I mix it with IF CASE maybe? What's more, zero exepction needs to be added

Answer (score 2):

Use `case`:

```
select (c = (case when operation = '+' then a + b
                  when operation = '-' then a - b
                  when operation = '/' then a / nullif(b, 0)
                  . . .
             end)
       ) as expected_equals_actual
```

Comment: SELECT id, a, b, operation, 

                           (SELECT CASE
                            when operation = '+' then CAST((a + b) as BINARY)
                            when operation = '-' then CAST((a - b) as BINARY)
                            when operation = '/' then CAST((a / b) as BINARY)
                            when operation = '*' then CAST((a * b) as BINARY)
                            end) as c

Comment: Even when it is incorrect, it is still shown and i've got problem with null. 3/0 should be zero not null

Comment: @Kermi Division by zero is not going to return zero. It's going to error out, which `NULL` represents.